# Craft can’t connect to the database with the credentials in craft/config/db.php

Tags: craft3, database, config, php

I'm trying to upgrade from 2.7.10 to Craft 3. I follow the [instructions/ docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/upgrade.html#performing-the-upgrade) to the letter, go to https://###.com/admin and am greeted with the above can't connect to database message.

So far, I have pretty much done everything to eliminate possibilities and the conclusion I have come to is that the `.env` file isn't being loaded. Obviously, I could well be wrong, but I tried a `die` `Hello World` on the `db.php` file and it worked. I put the database details directly into the `db.php` file and it worked, albeit took me to the current install rather than the upgrade page. I even created a new database (just to try it) and still got the same error.

The db file looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Database Configuration
 *
 * All of your system's database connection settings go in here. You can see a
 * list of the available settings in vendor/craftcms/cms/src/config/DbConfig.php.
 *
 * @see craft\config\DbConfig
 */

return [
    'driver' => getenv('DB_DRIVER'),
    'server' => getenv('DB_SERVER'),
    'user' => getenv('DB_USER'),
    'password' => getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'database' => getenv('DB_DATABASE'),
    'schema' => getenv('DB_SCHEMA'),
    'tablePrefix' => getenv('DB_TABLE_PREFIX'),
    'port' => getenv('DB_PORT')
];
```

And the env file:

```
# The environment Craft is currently running in ('dev', 'staging', 'production', etc.)
ENVIRONMENT="dev"

# The secure key Craft will use for hashing and encrypting data
SECURITY_KEY="*************"

# The database driver that will be used ('mysql' or 'pgsql')
DB_DRIVER="mysql"

# The database server name or IP address (usually this is 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1')
DB_SERVER="localhost"

# The database username to connect with
DB_USER="####"

# The database password to connect with
DB_PASSWORD="**************"

# The name of the database to select
DB_DATABASE="####"

# The database schema that will be used (PostgreSQL only)
DB_SCHEMA="public"

# The prefix that should be added to generated table names (only necessary if multiple things are sharing the same database)
DB_TABLE_PREFIX="craft"

# The port to connect to the database with. Will default to 5432 for PostgreSQL and 3306 for MySQL.
DB_PORT="3306"
```

Can anyone shed anymore light on how I can resolve this please? I am new to this so please be gentle and let me know if you need more info. 
Thanks.

Comment: Is this error on the command line, or on front-end?

Comment: Front-end.  I'm not using Composer or anything if that helps.

Comment: It's strange that it works directly from the db.php. What's your local server setup, is it MAMP or something else? It's a long shot (I don't think it's this) but have you tried 127.0.0.1 as your server setting?

Comment: I'm not using MAMP, I have uploaded it via FTP.  I also tested it on another server (for a different website) and go the same message, but, again, when I put the details directly into the db.php it worked.  I did try changing the server to 127.0.0.1 but got the same issue.

Comment: Hopefully, someone else may be able to help, but I think my next step would be to try a fresh install of Craft 3 in the same environment to see if it's an issue with your install or the environment.

Comment: OK, thanks. To be honest, I've tried fresh installing twice and I'm still getting the same error. Thanks again.

Comment: In that case, I would say something is up with your environment, have you tried the craft server checker? https://github.com/craftcms/server-check

Comment: I haven't.  I'll give it a go.  Thanks for this.

Comment: The server checker all came back fine, except the ini_sets, but this is because the server uses PHP-FPM rather than standard PHP. However, I'm not sure this should make a difference as Craft2 is installed without issue, although I could be wrong.

Comment: Have you checked out your server php logs to see if there's anything there? Also worth checking Craft's web.log, but have a feeling this may not show much. Failing that I would probably get in touch with Craft support.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I'm in touch with Brad now and I think it is agreed that the values from the .env file aren't being loaded. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @deebie77 did you able to solve this issue?